# How to call render functions in Vue 3 composition api?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Back in vue 2 i used to call `render()` like that:

```
export default {
    mounted(){
        ...
    },
    render(){
        ...
    },
    methods(){
        ...
    }
}
```

I'm now trying to do the same with Vue 3 and the composition api. Here is what i tried:

```
export default {
    ...
    setup(props, context){
        ...
        const create_canvas = (h, id, props) => {
            _id.value = id
            _attrs.value = props.attrs
            return () => h('div', {
                class: `trading-vue-${id}`,
                style: {
                    left: props.position.x + 'px',
                    top: props.position.y + 'px',
                    position: 'absolute',
                }
            }, [
                h('canvas', Object.assign({
                    id: `${props.tv_id}-${id}-canvas`,
                    onmousemove: e => renderer.mousemove(e),
                    onmouseout: e => renderer.mouseout(e),
                    onmouseup: e => renderer.mouseup(e),
                    onmousedown: e => renderer.mousedown(e),
                    ref: 'canvas',
                    style: props.style,
                }, props.attrs))
            ].concat(props.hs || []))
        };

        function render() {
            const id = props.grid_id
            const layout = props.layout.grids[id]
            return () => create_canvas(h, `grid-${id}`, {
                position: {
                    x: 0,
                    y: layout.offset || 0
                },
                attrs: {
                    width: layout.width,
                    height: layout.height,
                    overflow: 'hidden'
                },
                style: {
                    backgroundColor: props.colors.back
                },
                hs: [
                    h(Crosshair, Object.assign(
                        common_props(),
                        layer_events
                    )),
                    h(KeyboardListener, keyboard_events),
                    h(UxLayer, {
                        id,
                        tv_id: props.tv_id,
                        uxs: uxs.value,
                        colors: props.colors,
                        config: props.config,
                        updater: Math.random(),
                        onCustomEvent: emit_ux_event
                    })
                ].concat(get_overlays(h))
            })
        };

        render()
    }
}
```

This doesn't seem to return anything in my template. I think that i'm not calling the `render` function in the right way. Can anyone help me understanding how to use it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per my understanding, `h()` is a short form to create the vnodes and accept 3 parameters.

```
h(
    tag name,
    props/attributes,
    array of children
)
```

As per my understanding, In `create_canvas` you are trying to create a `div` which contains a `class` and `inline styles` as a props/attributes and we are creating a `canvas` as a children of this `div` vnode. Hence, Instead of returning the `vNode`  directly from setup(), it should return a render function that returns a `vNode`.

```
export default {
    props: {
      // props will come here
    },
    setup(props) {
        // render() { h(...) } ❌
           return () => {
               h('div', {
                class: `trading-vue-${id}`,
                style: {
                    left: props.position.x + 'px',
                    top: props.position.y + 'px',
                    position: 'absolute',
                }
            }, [
                h('canvas', Object.assign({
                    id: `${props.tv_id}-${id}-canvas`,
                    onmousemove: e => renderer.mousemove(e),
                    onmouseout: e => renderer.mouseout(e),
                    onmouseup: e => renderer.mouseup(e),
                    onmousedown: e => renderer.mousedown(e),
                    ref: 'canvas',
                    style: props.style,
                }, props.attrs))
            ].concat(props.hs || []))
       } ✅
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

First you are are not "calling" render function - you are just declaring it (Vue is caling it when rendering)

In Composition API you just need to [return render function](https://vuejs.org/guide/extras/render-function.html#declaring-render-functions) from `setup`

```js
import { ref, h } from 'vue'

export default {
  props: {
    /* ... */
  },
  setup(props) {
    const count = ref(1)

    // return the render function
    return () => h('div', props.msg + count.value)
  }
}
```

After applying this knowledge on your own code I would say that the last line of `setup` should not be `render()` but `return render()` (because the the `render()` function itself returns actual "render" function)

---

In JS functions are treated as data - you can store them in variables and return them from the functions. When the function is stored or returned as a result of another function, it is not executed immediately - it is only created. The one who calls the "factory" function (in this case factory function is `setup()` and the caller is Vue) can store the reference to the returned function and **decides when to call it**

The Vue [Composition API onMounted hook](https://vuejs.org/api/composition-api-lifecycle.html#onmounted) works very similarly. You are calling `onMounted()` passing a newly created function as an argument. `onMounted` stores the reference to the function somewhere so the Vue can later call it.

The point is that it does not matter that in `setup()` the `onMounted()` is executed 1st and your render function is returned as a last statement of `setup`. Because Vue decides when to call them "sometimes later". And it is reasonable to expect that Vue for sure will call your render function at least once before calling a function passed into `onMounted()` (because component cannot be mounted before it is rendered)

Comment: Thanks! So, in this case i should do `return () => create_canvas(...)`?

Comment: @JayK23 you may need to wrap into an array if you want to have several at top level too.

Comment: Is using `return` the only way to go? When i use `render()` in the options api, i can access the elements i created in `render` inside of `mounted()`. In this case, if i create the elements in `return` in cannot access them from `onMounted()`, since `onMounted` is executed before the `return`. Am i wrong?

Comment: @JayK23 why would you want to access them anyway? You could totally mix `setup` and `mounted`, should work fine IMO.

Comment: @JayK23 Yes you are wrong. I'v edited my answer with more explanation...